# How Can I Display a Document Library in one Web App from another Web App - SharePoint 2007

Tags: development

I've got a customer request where a Document Library exists in a Site Collection on one Web Application and they would like to display the items in another Site Collection in a different Web Application (Both Web Apps are in the same Domain) in SharePoint 2007.  Do I create a custom web part, or is there something Out of Box (Data View, jQuery, etc.) ?

Bismarck

Comment: I've a similar requirement. Can you give some pointers? (URLs may be!)

Answer (score 4):

Permissions and auth will be the bugaboos, but using the Web Services via SPServices and jQuery might do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Page Viewer Web Part + an SPD-edited DocLib view based on a no-chrome masterpage could do the trick if only the permissions to the other app did not matter.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this a couple of years ago and couldn't find an out of the box solution. I ended up writing a custom web part, but there are some third party solutions